# How to change the size of background 9patch image according to the size of child textview

Tags: android, xml, nine-patch

I am making a chat bubble. I made the bubble using 9patch image. But I want to resize the bubble according to the size of textview.. How to do it ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/senderbubble2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_msg"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above is my xml code of chat bubble...

Comment: Set the background of the parent layout.

Comment: I tried but its not working @Ahamed

Comment: Shall I edit your code?

Comment: 9patch automatically auto adjusts it size itself. With the layout you write here no matter if you put the background in the linear or in the text view, should work.
Do you check that the 9patch is well formed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height & width of textView, by calling below methods on textview reference, below method returns int value, you can use it to resize image.

```
textView.getMeasuredHeight();
textView.getMeasuredWidth();

If you want the height/width of text in textView you can try

Rect bounds = new Rect();

textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds)
```

see documentation for more details
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html